replaced C function with assembly, now segfaulting after main exits
Working on an assignment, the premise is essentially implementing provided C functions in assembly and preserving behavior.
The program reads "records" from stdin (char* last_name, char* first_name, long id), stores them in a RECORD* heap[], and performs some sorting.
I'm only replacing one function right now, the read_record function, and somehow getting a segmentation fault after main exits (trying to access (%rdi) which is 0x0 in dyld). Running on a Macbook M2. I've been debugging with lldb and think I've ruled out:

stack corruption (%rsp, %rbp remain the same before and after each call to read_record)
memory leaks (ran with address sanitizer & leaks with no leaks detected. I free() each record before returning from main as well.)

I've been bashing my head into a wall on this for hours, so any pointers would be appreciated.
Here's my C file:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/***********************************************************

This program implements a simple priority queue using a heap.
The items being sorted are records, where each record contains a last name, a 
first name, and an ID number.  The records will be sorted according 
to their ID numbers, from smallest to largest.

A heap (in this context) is a binary tree with the following 
properties:
- The value at a parent node is greater than the value at 
  either child node.
- The heap is implemented using an array. Each element of the
  array is a pointer to a record. 
- For a parent node at index i of the array, the children are 
  found at indices (i*2)+1 and (i*2)+2. All parent nodes
  have two children, except for the very last parent node.
- For a child node at index i of the array, the parent is
  found at index (x-1)/2 (using integer division).

************************************************************/

// This is the declaration of the RECORD type

typedef struct  {
  char *last_name;
  char *first_name;
  long id_number;
} RECORD;


RECORD *read_record();

/* This function reads in the data for a single record from the
   standard input by calling scanf. If scanf succeeds in 
   reading the data, a new RECORD is allocated, populated
   with the data, and a pointer to the record is returned 
*/


// RECORD *read_record()
// {
//   char lastname[100], firstname[100];
//   RECORD *p;
//   long id;
//   int res = scanf("%s %s %ld", lastname, firstname, &id);
//   if (res == EOF)   // EOF is -1
//     return NULL;
//   p = malloc(sizeof(RECORD));
//   p->last_name = malloc(strlen(lastname)+1);
//   strcpy(p->last_name, lastname);
//   p->first_name = malloc(strlen(lastname)+1);
//   strcpy(p->first_name, firstname);  
//   p->id_number = id;
//   return p;
// }



/*
  These are macros that are convenient for finding the parent,
  left child, and right child of a node at index x of the array.
*/

#define PARENT(x) ((x-1)>>1)
#define LEFT(x) ((x<<1)+1)
#define RIGHT(x) ((x<<1)+2)


// This is the fixed size of the heap array.

#define SIZE 500

// The heap is an array of pointers to records
RECORD *heap[SIZE];

// This is a count of the number of nodes in the head.
// It is also the index of the next available slot in the
// array.

// int heap_count = 0;
extern int heap_count; // in assembly
void heap_swap(int i, int j); // Victor reference to keep prototype


/* 
  This function simply swaps the contents of the heap
  array at indices i and j.  The contents of each 
  element of the array is just a pointer to a record.
*/


void heap_swap(int i, int j) {
  RECORD *temp = heap[i];
  heap[i] = heap[j];
  heap[j] = temp;
}



void sift_up(int i);

/* 
   This is the heap "sift up" function. It starts with a leaf, at array index i, that has just
   been added to the tree and might violate the heap requirement (i.e. the value of the leaf
   may be less than that of its parent). It works by comparing the node at index i to 
   its parent.  If the value of the node is not less than its parent, the heap property
   has been maintained and the function can return.  Otherwise, the values at the node and at its
   parent are swapped, i is set to the index of the parent node (since the value at the parent now 
   may be less than at the grandparent), and the process iterates until either the heap property
   is satisfied or the root (at index 0) is reached.
*/


void sift_up(int i)
{
  while (i != 0) {
    if (heap[i]->id_number >= heap[PARENT(i)]->id_number)   // correct situation, no need to continue
    return;
    // otherwise, need to swap with parent
    heap_swap(i, PARENT(i));
    i = PARENT(i);
  }
}


void sift_down();


/* 
   This function performs the heap "sift down" process, which occurs when
   a new value has been inserted at the root of the tree (i.e. when the 
   existing root is removed and the last leaf in the tree is inserted at
   the root). Starting at the root as the parent node, the values of the 
   two child nodes are compared to each other. Then if the value at the
   parent is greater than the value at the smaller child, the values at
   the parent and the smaller child are swapped, and the process
   continues with the smaller child being considered the parent in the
   next iteration.  The process terminates when a leaf is reached.

   At any point, if the value at the parent is not greater than the 
   smaller child, the heap property has been preserved and the function
   can return. If a parent ony has one child (which must be the left 
   child), then the left child is considered the smaller child.
*/


void sift_down()
{
  int i = 0;
  int last_parent = PARENT(heap_count - 1);
  int min_child;
  
  while (i <= last_parent) {
    if ((RIGHT(i) >= heap_count) ||
    (heap[LEFT(i)]->id_number <= heap[RIGHT(i)]->id_number))
      min_child = LEFT(i);
    else
      min_child = RIGHT(i);
    if (heap[i]->id_number > heap[min_child]->id_number) {
      heap_swap(i, min_child);
      i = min_child;
    }
    else // done sifting down
      return;
  }
}




void heap_insert(RECORD *p);

/*
   This function inserts a new record into the 
   heap. It does so by adding a pointer to the 
   record at index heap_count (the first open
   slot) in the array and then calling
   sift_up(), above, to restore the heap property.
*/


void heap_insert(RECORD *p)
{
  if (heap_count >= SIZE) {
    printf("Error: Heap is full\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  heap[heap_count] = p;
  sift_up(heap_count);
  heap_count++;
}



RECORD *heap_remove();

/* 
    This function removes the smallest  value in the heap, i.e.
    the value at the root node (at array index 0), and returns 
    that smallest value (which is a pointer to a record).
    Before returning, it writes the value of the last
    leaf (at index heap_count-1 of the array) into to the 
    root node and then calls    sift_down(), above, to 
    restore the heap property.
*/


RECORD *heap_remove()  
{
  if (heap_count <= 0) {
    printf("Error: Heap is empty\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  RECORD *result = heap[0];
  heap_count--;
  heap[0] = heap[heap_count];
  sift_down();
  return result;
}



/* 

   This is the main function, which repeatedly calls read_record and
   heap_insert to insert pointers to records into the heap. Once
   all the data has been read, it repeatedly calls heap_remove()
   to print out the records in sorted order, according the ID number
*/

int main() {
  RECORD *p = NULL;
  p = read_record();
  while (p != NULL) {
    printf("Inserting %ld: %s, %s\n", p->id_number, p->last_name, p->first_name);
    heap_insert(p);
    p = read_record();
  }
  
  printf("Sorted\n------\n");
  while (heap_count != 0) {
    p = heap_remove();
    printf("%ld: %s, %s\n", p->id_number, p->last_name, p->first_name);
    if (p) {
      free(p->last_name);
      free(p->first_name);
      free(p);
      p = NULL;
    }
  }

  system("leaks assign3");
}

and my assembly code:
.data
    .globl format_string
    format_string:
        .asciz "%s %s %ld"

.text
    .globl _read_record

_read_record:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    # Allocate space for local variables (aligned to 16 bytes)
    subq    $224, %rsp          # Allocate space (100 + 100 + 8 bytes)

    # Prepare arguments for scanf
    leaq    -100(%rbp), %rsi    # lastname buffer
    leaq    -200(%rbp), %rdx    # firstname buffer
    leaq    -216(%rbp), %rcx    # id_number buffer
    leaq    format_string(%rip), %rdi # format string

    # Call scanf
    call    _scanf
    testl    %eax, %eax
    js      .return_null        # If scanf fails, return NULL

    # Allocate space for RECORD
    movq    $24, %rdi           # sizeof(RECORD)
    call    _malloc
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je      .return_null
    movq    %rax, %rbx          # Store RECORD pointer in %rbx

    # Allocate and copy last_name
    leaq    -100(%rbp), %rdi    # lastname buffer
    call    _strlen
    addq    $1, %rax            # Include null terminator
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _malloc
    movq    %rax, (%rbx)        # Save pointer to last_name
    leaq    -100(%rbp), %rsi    # Copy lastname to allocated memory
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _strcpy

    # Allocate and copy first_name
    leaq    -200(%rbp), %rdi    # firstname buffer
    call    _strlen
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _malloc
    movq    %rax, 8(%rbx)       # Save pointer to first_name
    leaq    -200(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _strcpy

    # Set id_number
    movq    -216(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rbx)      # Save id_number

    # Return RECORD pointer
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    addq    $224, %rsp          # Restore stack
    popq    %rbp                
    retq

.return_null:
    movq    $0, %rax            # Return NULL
    addq    $224, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq

Output of leaks:
leaks -atExit -- ./assign3 < input.txt
leaks(85603) MallocStackLogging: could not tag MSL-related memory as no_footprint, so those pages will be included in process footprint - (null)
assign3(85604) MallocStackLogging: could not tag MSL-related memory as no_footprint, so those pages will be included in process footprint - (null)
Inserting 183543766: Horvath, Zsuzsanna
Sorted
------
183543766: Horvath, Zsuzsanna
sh(85610) MallocStackLogging: could not tag MSL-related memory as no_footprint, so those pages will be included in process footprint - (null)
bash(85610) MallocStackLogging: could not tag MSL-related memory as no_footprint, so those pages will be included in process footprint - (null)
leaks(85610) MallocStackLogging: could not tag MSL-related memory as no_footprint, so those pages will be included in process footprint - (null)
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==85604==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x00020245d38e bp 0x00030883a450 sp 0x00030883a240 T0)
==85604==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==85604==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x20245d38e  (<unknown module>)

==85604==Register values:
rax = 0x0000000000000000  rbx = 0x0000603000001ae0  rcx = 0xda72101f757600da  rdx = 0x0000000000000000  
rdi = 0x0000000000000000  rsi = 0x0000000000000000  rbp = 0x000000030883a450  rsp = 0x000000030883a240  
 r8 = 0x0000100061107430   r9 = 0x0000000000000000  r10 = 0x0000100061107436  r11 = 0x00000fffffffffff  
r12 = 0x000000030883a260  r13 = 0x0000000000000000  r14 = 0x0000000000000000  r15 = 0x000000030883a3e0  
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (<unknown module>) 
==85604==ABORTING
leaks(85613) MallocStackLogging: could not tag MSL-related memory as no_footprint, so those pages will be included in process footprint - (null)
Can't examine target process's malloc zone asan_0x10bbc65f8, so memory analysis will be incomplete or incorrect.
Reason: for security, cannot load non-system library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib

Process:         assign3 [85604]
Path:            */assign3
Load Address:    0x1022fc000
Identifier:      assign3
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86-64 (translated)
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  leaks [85603]

Date/Time:       2024-11-23 03:55:49.906 -0800
Launch Time:     2024-11-23 03:55:47.808 -0800
OS Version:      macOS 14.4 (23E214)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/leaks

Physical footprint:         14.1M
Physical footprint (peak):  14.1M
Idle exit:                  untracked
----

leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 85604: 1 nodes malloced for 0 KB
Process 85604: 0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.


rbx should be preserved for your caller. Consult calling convention documentation.

Side note: you should not check for negative return from scanf, you should check if you got as many fields as you asked for.

@Jester I think that was it. Thank you!

@Jester: The return value of scanf should be checked for the number of assignments desired, not the number of fields processed. They may differ when assignments are suppressed.

Segfaulting after main runs a ret to return back to its caller?  Or segfaulting in main's epilogue?  On Linux with glibc, main's caller just does mov %eax, %edi / call exit, IIRC, so doesn't actually depend on main preserving any call-preserved registers.  I'm curious if macOS is different.  Or are you just segfaulting in main's epilogue, before it reaches its ret?  Did you compile your C with clang -fsanitize=undefined or something?  (Or is AddressSanitizer part of something leaks is doing?)

@PeterCordes since MacOS Monterey (12.x) the ret in main requires preserving  rbx as implementation detail of dyld4. MacOS Ventura being notable exception which requires rbp instead.
